# SVG working on html image tag -- not on HTML5 canvas

Tags: css, html, svg, mask, svg-filters

I have a problem here. I need something to be implemented onclick of a button. I searched on the net and found out that **SVG** was an easier way to do it rather than **CSS stylesheets.**

I have an **HTML5 canvas** (which is basically a snapshot from a video stream that I have taken and drawn on to the HTML 5 canvas using drawImage()). On click of a button, I want the image with the following effect to come on the canvas instead of the original image.

[image: original Image] 
[image: image with focal spotlight]

My problem is that I am able to replicate the effect if I apply the effect on just an image. However, on the canvas it gives me the mask separately and the image separately.    This is the code that I am using for the SVG

```
<svg height="0">
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask-radial">
        <rect width="500" height="500" fill="url(#g1)"></rect>
        <radialGradient id="g1" cx="80%" cy="80%" r="100%">
          <stop stop-color="black" offset="50%"/>
          <stop stop-color="white" offset="110%"/>
        </radialGradient>
      </mask>
      <!--<mask id="mask-linear">
        <rect width="400" height="300" fill="url(#l1)"></rect>
        <linearGradient id="l1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
          <stop stop-color="white" offset="0%"/>
          <stop stop-color="black" offset="30%"/>
          <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </mask>  -->
      <filter id="filtre1">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
      </filter>
     <!-- <filter id="filtre2">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10"/>
      </filter> -->
    </defs>
    </svg>
```

This is how I am calling it in **CSS**

```
   .effet{
  width: 500px; height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.effet img{
  position: absolute;
}
.filtre--r{
  -webkit-mask: -webkit-radial-gradient( center, closest-side, transparent 50%, black 80%);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient( closest-side at center, transparent 50%, black 80%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(40px);
  mask: url('#mask-radial');
  filter: url('#filtre1');
}
```

and these are my HTML elements.

```
<div class="effet">
  <img src="/static/images/noEffect.png" alt="" />
<img class="filtre filtre--r" src="/static/images/noEffect.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Can somebody please tell me how I can recreate the effect for my canvas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi all, I actually solved it using createRadialGradient property of HTML5 Canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched and found that HTML5 Canvas radial gradient was an effective solution.

```
        var lightSize = 100;
        var x = 200;
        var y = 200;

         var radialGradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0,x, y, lightSize);
          radialGradient.addColorStop(0, "#FFFF99"); // color at start circle
          radialGradient.addColorStop(0.9, "#FFFF99"); //color at offset 0.9
          radialGradient.addColorStop(1, '#7D7D5C');// color of finish circle  

          context.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
          context.fillStyle = radialGradient;
```

Was able to recreate the effect totally.

Comment: using SVG was still giving me that problem of creating the with effect in a separate canvas window.